# Using database/sql library and fetching password from vault when a new connection fails

Tags: go

I have a long running daemon written in Go, that listens to a port and spins up multiple go routines for every new connection to handle the data. There is a global variable `db` that is assigned connection context returned by `database/sql` library's `open()` function in the func main() of my script.

We store the db password in a vault which rotates it every couple of days for security reasons. I can fetch the password from the vault the first time it creates the connection context and the same context is used in all go routines for creating new db connections.
However, when the password is rotated by the vault, all new db connections fail. I would like to know what is the best way of handling this so that it fetches the password from the vault on failure and reconnects. If it was an oop language, I could extend the db library and override the connection function to catch the error and fetch password from the vault on connection failure. Is there a similar approach that can be used in Go or are there any other way of handling this? I am very new to Go, and apologies if I have not framed the question right.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "net"
)

var db *sql.DB
const port = "port number"

func main() {

    db, err = sql.Open("mysql","<Connection string that contains the password fetched from vault>")

    db.SetMaxOpenConns(100)

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+port)

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept() 

        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    // Uses db variable to connect to db.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by creating a custom driver that imports github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql and get registered in the sql package, so that when ever a new connection is required the custome driver can fetch password from vault and pass it down to mysql driver to open the connection. Refer the code sample below.

```
package vault-mysql-driver

import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type VaultMysqlDriver struct {
    *mysql.MySQLDriver
}

func updateDsn(dsn string) (string, err) {
    // logic to fetch password from vault and update dsn with the password
}

func (d VaultMysqlDriver) Open(dsn string) (driver.Conn, error) {

    updateddsn, err := updateDsn(dsn)

    // Pass down the dsn with password to mysql driver's open function
    return d.MySQLDriver.Open(updateddsn)

}

// When initialised will register the driver in sql package
func init() {
    sql.Register(vault-driver, &CyberarkMysqlDriver{&mysql.MySQLDriver{}})
}
```

This package is now imported in the daemon as below,

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "vault-mysql-driver"// init is invoked and it will get registered in sql package
    "net"
)

var db *sql.DB
const port = "port number"

func main() {
    // vault-driver is used instead of mysql so that the sql package knows to use the custom driver for new connections.
    db, err = sql.Open("vault-driver","<Connection string that contains the password fetched from vault>")

    db.SetMaxOpenConns(100)

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+port)

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept() 

        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    // Uses db variable to connect to db.
}
```

This way whenever the vault rotates the password there won't be any connection failure since the vault driver will always fetch password from vault for every new connections.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to create context on main?
why not create a separate package/namespace and perform db connections in there.
create a new namespace with methods...
createDBClient() this creates new db contexts by fetching password from vault and stores it in global var db
GetDBClient() this checks if the global var db has something in it, if so check if it can connect to db (https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Ping)
if not call createDBClient() loop this for few times with sleep if doesnt connect crash and burn
if it connects return the context

now in your handleConnection() call db := newnamespace.GetDBClient()

Comment: also the reason i said make different package/namespace is because if you are going to make var db global then anything under main can access that and modify, if it is in different namespace and variable or method starting with lowercase becomes private to that namespace, its much safer this way.

Comment: `sql.Open` does not create a connection. It only creates the context. Connection gets created when the query is executed which means in `handleConnection()`. I can catch the error and then reconnect but I don't want to wait for the query to fail to reconnect with new password, but instead catch the bad connection error and then create a new connection by fetching password from vault. However, I am unsure as to how I can catch the bad connection error since the library does not throw it(may be I am wrong).

Comment: yeah true, i meant to say context. updated answer with specific details

Comment: Does that mean we need to ping before every sql execution to check if connection is alive? The chances of it to fail are very rare so pinging every time is not feasible. That is the reason I wanted to catch bad connection error and then reconnect. The library does the job of checking if the connection is alive and if not try creating new connection with the saved context. All I wanted to do is when the library catches bad connection error and creates new connection, make it use the new password which could solve the problem.

Comment: not at every sql query, just before you start executing underlying queries inside your handleConnection(), so once everytime you execute this method.

Comment: It is a long running daemon and this method gets executed when ever a new tcp connection gets established which happens almost every time.

Comment: "All I wanted to do is when the library catches bad connection error and creates new connection, make it use the new password which could solve the problem." then you have to wait for query to fail and then retry.
either check before which is safer. ping only checks connection status doesnot execute any query or you have to wait for it to fail. i prefer ping over failing.

Comment: Agree that pinging is a good idea but not for this scenario because of various other constraints and we have thought about it. Waiting for the query to fail is the solution we had in mind but we wanted to make it better by handling it at the connection establishment level. The way we could do it in oop languages is by extending the library and overriding the function. However, my go skills are not that great and am still learning and am not sure if there is an equivalent approach in golang with composition.